# GNUplot stdin, how to plot multiple lines?

Tags: python, gnuplot, stdin

OK so I am piping data into GNUplot in the form of, e.g:

```
2013-11-04 20:00:12,875,350,112,29,38,4,44,10,632,121
```

<strike>I have set the following in my Python code:</strike>

```
gnuplot.stdin.write("plot '-' u 1:2 t 'aa',\
'' u 1:3 t 'aa in',\
'' u 1:4 t 'bb',\
'' u 1:5 t 'bb in',\
'' u 1:6 t 'cc',\
'' u 1:7 t 'cc in',\
'' u 1:8 t 'dd',\
'' u 1:9 t 'dd in',\
'' u 1:10 t 'ee';\n")
```

However I keep getting errors such as:

```
gnuplot> plot '-' u 1:2 t 'aa',    '' u 1:3 t 'aa in',    '' u 1:4 t 'bb',    '' u 1:5 t 'bb in',    '' u 1:6 t 'cc',    '' u 1:7 t 'cc in',    '' u 1:8 t 'dd',    '' u 1:9 t 'dd in',    '' u 1:10 t 'ee';
                                                   ^
         line 1271: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
```

<strike>Any ideas?</strike>

<strike>###UPDATE:###</strike>

Based on @Christoph's feedback; here's the code I'm currently using:

```
cur.execute(sql)
data = cur.fetchall()

c = 0            
for k in data:
    dataElement = data[c]    
    gnuplot.stdin.write("plot '-' u 1:2 t 'aa',\
    '' u 1:3 t 'aa in',\
    '' u 1:4 t 'bb',\
    '' u 1:5 t 'bb in',\
    '' u 1:6 t 'cc',\
    '' u 1:7 t 'cc in',\
    '' u 1:8 t 'dd',\
    '' u 1:9 t 'dd in',\
    '' u 1:10 t 'ee';\n")

    gnuplot.stdin.write("%s,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i\n" % dataElement[:])
    gnuplot.stdin.write("e\n")
    c = c + 1
```

Comment: Does it work without the titles?

Comment: @Bernhard No. I get the same errors as above, i.e.: `gnuplot> plot '-' u 1:2,    '' u 1:3,    '' u 1:4,    '' u 1:5,    '' u 1:6,    '' u 1:7,    '' u 1:8,    '' u 1:9,    '' u 1:10;`

Comment: @Christoph I have asked a more specific question with more focus as suggested (by you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code solved it:

```
gnuplot.stdin.write("plot '-' u 1:2 t 'aa', " + \
            " '-' u 1:2 t 'aa in', " + \
            "'-' u 1:2 t 'bb', " + \
            "'-' u 1:2 t 'bb in', " + \
            "'-' u 1:2 t 'cc', " + \
            "'-' u 1:2 t 'cc in', " + \
            "'-' u 1:2 t 'dd', " + \
            "'-' u 1:2 t 'dd in', " + \
            "'-' u 1:2 t 'ee', " + \
            "'-' u 1:2 t 'ee in';\n")

for n in range(10):
    for dataElement in data:        
        a = n + 1
        if a == 11:
            break
        else:
            gnuplot.stdin.write("%s,%i\n" % (dataElement[0],dataElement[a]))
    gnuplot.stdin.write("e\n")
gnuplot.stdin.flush()
```

Answer (score 3):

You must write an own data block for each `'-'`. The `''` saves you only from retyping the file name, but doesn't reuse the data. Consider e.g. the following gnuplot script:

```
plot '-', '-'
2
4
6
e
10
12
14
e
```

Also make sure, that your delimiter is set properly: `set datafile separator ','`.

Here is a minimal python script, which plots two data sets from `stdin`, with the columns separated by comma:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

gnuplot = subprocess.Popen(["gnuplot"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

gp_wrt = gnuplot.stdin.write

gp_wrt("set terminal pngcairo\n")
gp_wrt("set output 'test.png'\n")
gp_wrt("set datafile separator ','\n")
gp_wrt("plot '-' with lines title 'mytitle',\
'-' with lines title 'other title'\n")
for i in range(11):
    gp_wrt("{},{}\n".format(i, i**2))
gp_wrt("e\n")

for i in range(11):
    gp_wrt("{},{}\n".format(i, (0.5*i)**2))
gp_wrt("e\n")
```

So for your data it may look like

```
gnuplot.stdin.write("plot '-' u 1:2 t 'aa',\
    '' u 1:3 t 'aa in',\
    '' u 1:4 t 'bb',\
    '' u 1:5 t 'bb in',\
    '' u 1:6 t 'cc',\
    '' u 1:7 t 'cc in',\
    '' u 1:8 t 'dd',\
    '' u 1:9 t 'dd in',\
    '' u 1:10 t 'ee';\n")

for i in range(10):
    for dataElement in data:
        gnuplot.stdin.write("%s,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i\n" % dataElement[:])
    gnuplot.stdin.write("e\n")
```

But in that case you could simply use:

```
gnuplot.stdin.write("plot '-' u 1:2 t 'aa',\
    '' u 1:2 t 'aa in',\
    '' u 1:2 t 'bb',\
    '' u 1:2 t 'bb in',\
    '' u 1:2 t 'cc',\
    '' u 1:2 t 'cc in',\
    '' u 1:2 t 'dd',\
    '' u 1:2 t 'dd in',\
    '' u 1:2 t 'ee';\n")

for i in range(10):
    for dataElement in data:
        gnuplot.stdin.write("%s,%i\n" % (dataElement[0], dataElement[i])
    gnuplot.stdin.write("e\n")
```

i.e. each time you write only the relevant columns.

Comment: I have put `gnuplot.stdin.write("e\n")` after each time the data is sent and I am getting somewhere with this. All the relevant data points are now showing up with respective legends. However, I am a little stuck; the first row have been accepted but none of the following rows of data are. I do not follow your `plot '-', '-'` part?

Comment: That was meant as a pure gnuplot script and should show, that for two `'-'` parts you need to send the data twice, each time terminated with an `e`. I added a minimal python script, which plots two data sets coming from stdin.

Comment: I have 440 lines to submit through stdin to gnuplot. Are you telling me I need 439 `'-', ` after `plot ` ending with `'-';` and then looping through the data to be submitted?

Comment: With 'lines' do you mean a line in the plot (severy connected points) or a row in the data set? And if you indeed have 440 lines to plot, then you need as many `'-'`, but I can't believe that, especially with all of them having keys :) If you have 440 rows in a data set, which are connected together to a single line in the plot, then you need only a single `'-'`.

Comment: I have included the code in my original question; that's what I think you mean. Is it?

Comment: No its not! Please take the time to study my script a bit. Whats the meaning of `data`? what information does it hold? How do you want them to be displayed? Do you e.g. want to have all values in column 4 to be connected? Do you have the possiblity to upload your data somewhere? I think we're not getting together, from reading your code, I don't understand how your result should look like. Your still messing around with all those `'-'` and `''`. And consider writing the complete string to an external file to see how it looks like.

Comment: I added to my answer what I mean.

Comment: I have updated my code so that you see where `data` comes from. It is the tuple of tuples returned from the query to the MySQL DB. I unpack each tuple in `data` to a single tuple called `dataElement` and then I use dataElement to feed in the values to stdin (to end up at gnuplot).

Comment: "Do you e.g. want to have all values in column 4 to be connected?" Yes, I want all values in each position to be connected with the same values in the same position each time a record/line is fed into stdin from dataElement[:]. The output will be time (x), value (y). If you look at how I have shown the way the data is sent, the first values is a time-stamp, subsequent values are y-values.

Comment: "Do you have the possiblity to upload your data somewhere?" No I do not want to dump the values to a separate data file and feed that into gnuplot. Hence why I'm doing this from stdin.

Comment: "And consider writing the complete string to an external file to see how it looks like" The complete line piped into stdin is shown in my first post at the top. Here's my current output for clarity: http://i.imgur.com/UCicpb8.png . Problem is, only the first values are plotted.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe space-delimited data to this tool instead:

https://github.com/dkogan/feedgnuplot

It'll feed gnuplot thing the right commands, and make plots. Use --dump if you want to get a gnuplot script out of it.